# Change Arabic digits to English while phone language is Arabic

Tags: applications, languages, localization

Every time I set Arabic language it comes with Arabic digits, and could make them English Format by [MoreLocale 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.c_lis.ccl.morelocale) App, that needs grant with *adb* `permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION`.
Now I would do this without 3rd party apps, I didn't find anything similar in **build.prop** file, and I don't know how ?

> Arabic digits : (٠‎ - ١‎ - ٢‎ - ٣‎ -٤‎ - ٥‎ - ٦‎ - ٧‎ - ٨‎ - ٩)

Comment: Are you asking how to make the same locale change without using any apps? Why?

Comment: @DanHulme Yes I want to change the language in the phone settings to Arabic but keep English digits, I believe it's only 2 letters change because if I set language to AR and location to DZ, in the app mentioned in the main question then it will be set to to English digits + Arabic language that's what I want to do without 3rd party app.